# How to print the content of an array in phpfox

Tags: php, smarty, phpfox

I'm working on a legacy application that is written in [PHPfox](http://www.phpfox.com/).

There is this `foreach` loop in one of my view.html.php files:

```
{foreach from=$aReportSubmissions key=iKey item=aReportSubmission}
    <td>{$aReportSubmission.event_name}</td>
{/foreach}
```

The problem is that `$aReportSubmission.event_name` is an array and it gets outputted as Array. How can I loop through this variable and show the individual events?

PHPfox uses template tags that resemble Smarty template engine.

The following did NOT work for me:

```
{foreach from=$aReportSubmission.event_name item=iEvent} {iEvent},{/foreach}
```

Comment: Does [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I can see `$` is missing before **`iEvent`** inside the inner loop

Check if this is works

```
{foreach from=$aReportSubmissions key=iKey item=aReportSubmission}
    <td>{foreach from=$aReportSubmission.event_name item=iEvent} {$iEvent},{/foreach}</td>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 {foreach from=$aReportSubmissions key=iKey item=aReportSubmission}
    {$aReportSubmission.event_name|print_r}
{/foreach}
```